# Find the condition for a center of a circle with exactly one lattice point on its circumference

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, solution-verification, plane-curves

Statement

> Find the condition for a center of a circle with exactly one lattice point on its circumference (this lattice point must not be the only one lattice point of the disk)

**What I have tried:**

Part I:

Let $$\mathcal C: (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$$ be a circle positioned at $K(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb R^2$ and $\varepsilon$ be a tangent line to this circle of the form
$$\varepsilon : (x-x_0)x_1 + (y-y_0)y_1 = r^2$$ where $P(x_1,y_1)$ is the intersection point.

Our circle $C$ will contain exactly one lattice point $W \in \mathbb Z^2$ if and only  if there is only one pair of integers such that $P \equiv W$. In other words (geometrically) the circle has only one tangent passing from a lattice point.

Our problem reduces to finding the condition that $K$ must satisfy in order for $\varepsilon$ to have exactly one integer solution $W'(x',y')$. Therefore let $A = x - x_0, B = y-y_0, r^2 = C > 0$ which leads to a much simpler form: $$Ax_1 + By_1 = C$$

If $B=0$ then the line $x_1 = C/A$ has either no or infinite number of integer solutions. Therefore $B \neq 0 $.

Note that $Ax' + By' = C$ so $$A(x-x') = -B(y-y') \iff y-y' = - \frac A B (x- x')$$

If $ (-A/B) \in \mathbb Q $ then there exist infinitely many sets of integers $(x_1, y_1)$ where $x_1 \neq x'$ which implies that $- A /  B $ is irrational **(1)**.

Part II:

Now let $\mathcal C$ be parametrized as follows:

$$\mathcal C: A = r \cos t, \quad B  = r \sin t \; \text{such that} \; t \in [0, 2 \pi)$$ which means that $\cot (-t)$ must be irrational according to **(1)** for all $t \in (0, 2 \pi) - \{ \pi \} = S$. 
Hence for a random $t \in S$ where $\cot (-t) \in \mathbb Q^c$ we know that there would exist a circle with exactly one lattice point on its circumference.

My questions:

1. Is the above right and complete (I am not sure for Part II of the proof)?
2. Are there other solutions to the problem?

Comment: It seems to me that given any point with neither coordinate a half-integer there's a circle centered at that point with exactly one lattice point on its circumference, namely, the circle through the (unique) nearest lattice point.

Comment: The point must not be unique

Comment: Huh? You are asking for "exactly one lattice point on its circumference". If that doesn't make the point unique, I don't know what does. Maybe you should rewrite your question, so I can understand it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Corrected it.

Comment: Corrected it? The only change you made was to add the phrase, "this point must not be the only one on the disk." Now we don't usually speaking of points being on a disk. We speak of points being on a circle, and of points being in a disk. I don't know which you mean (or if maybe you mean something else entirely). Moreover, any disk of nonzero radius has infinitely many points, both inside it and on its circumference. But maybe when you say "point" you mean "lattice point". So can I ask you to further correct your question, so it says what it means to say?

Comment: You are using $C$ for your circle, but you are also using it for a number in $r^2=C$ and what follows. Also, if you parametrize a circle by $(r\cos t,r\sin t)$ then you get a circle centered at the origin, which is not consistent with the rest of the exposition.

Comment: By the way, I think the answer is, let $P=(a,b)$ be any point with neither $a$ nor $b$ half an odd integer, and with $a$ and $b$ not both integers. Then there are circles centered at $P$ with arbitrarily large numbers of interior lattice points and exactly one lattice point on the circumference.

Comment: Apologies for bad notation. As for the parametrization $ \mathcal C: x = x_0 + r \cos t, y = y_0 + r \sin t$ therefore $A,B$ are expressed correctly in terms of $t$. Provide with proofs for what you state as complete answers.

Comment: "Provide with proofs for what you state as complete answers." Sorry, are you giving me an order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer. Call a point $(x,y)$ *ordinary* if $2x$ is not an odd integer, $2y$ is not an odd integer, $x+y$ is not an integer, and $x-y$ is not an integer. It's not hard to see that if $(x,y)$ is ordinary then it has a unique nearest lattice point and a unique second-nearest lattice point. So if $(x,y)$ is ordinary then the circle centered at $(x,y)$ with radius equal to the distance to the second-nearest lattice point will enclose the nearest lattice point and will have exactly one lattice point on its circumference.